# Why does the compiler say this macro function needs a closing parenthesis?

Tags: c++

The code is below. The compiler says "Expected a )", but I do not get it: ( and ) are matching. What did I do wrong?

[image]

```
#define CR_SUCCESS 0

#define EXIT_IF_FAILS(varResult, callString) \
    (\
        varResult = callString; \
        if(varResult != CR_SUCCESS) \
        { \
            return -1; \
        } \
    )

int testFunction(int a, int b)
{
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int result;
    EXIT_IF_FAILS(result, testFunction(1, 2));

}
```

Comment: Macros aren't functions, they aren't called but rather substituted as text. Is the substituted `( ... = ... ; if(...) {...} )` valid **as code**?

Comment: Did you mean to put that code block inside curly braces `{}` instead of parentheses `()`??

Comment: When I searched for macro function examples, all the multi-line examples were enclosing the body with ( and ), so I thought that the parentheses were a part of the macro syntax. It seems that my assumption was wrong; I removed the  parentheses, and it was compiled.

Comment: @KenWhite I count three closing parentheses in the expanded version. One after `(1, 2)`, one after `!= 0)`, and one after `{return -1; } )`.

Comment: Damn sweet of the IDE to show the expanded version. Why when I was a kid we got *Syntax error on line 6694*. And the program only had, say, 30 lines. Kids got it easy these days.

Comment: I suspect the examples you found were either (a) plain (complex) expressions with no statements, or (b) using the GNU extension `({ ... })`. Either way, the macro here is not an improvement. It saves on typing, not on mental complexity.

Comment: @NathanPierson: You're right. Old eyes and the lack of contrast in the expanded text is where I'm assigning the blame. :-) Well, that and the fact that fonts aren't scaled in images, no matter what size you have text in your browser.

Comment: As an aside, there's little reason to use function-like macros in modern C++. You should prefer inline functions (or even just functions, letting the optimising compiler figure out what's best). Especially in a case where you save no lines whatsoever: `if ((result = testFunction(1, 2)) != CR_SUCCESS) return -1;`

Comment: @paxdiablo But I want to exit the function with that macro. If I use an actual function, how can I exit the caller from the function? Unless I check the result of the function and exists in the caller, which defeats the purpose of the function.

Comment: @DamnVegetables One option would be throwing an exception. This will exit the surrounding function, unless it explicitly decides to handle the exception.

Comment: @KenWhite "Lack of contrast" is a general problem I encounter in numerous current applications in "Dark Theme". For some reason, the developers mostly use light-grey text on grey background, like Android Studio, Visual Studio, Blender, etc, and it lacks contrast, making it difficult to read the text. That sucks. I could change the background of VS's text editor to pure black, but I forgot (or it is impossible) to change the background colour of the pop-up.

Comment: @user4581301 I am using VS 2022 preview 4, and it has the A.I. code assisting which predicts (at least in C#) the line (not just a variable, but the whole line of code) I was trying to type and it is great.

Comment: @DamnVegetables: for this particular use case, yes, inline functions are inappropriate. I probably should have clarified that (which I'm doing now). That's why I also gave the one-line code snippet which makes the whole macro unnecessary.

Comment: Sadly I work in a slow-moving environment. By the time I get to upgrade from VS2010 I'll probably be in a museum exhibit featuring fossils of Ancient Man from the Silicon Ages.

Comment: @paxdiablo Actually, that was not the whole code of the macro function. I removed some of the lines to make it easier to figure out the error, in actual code, there were lines to print the error before exiting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding, your `main` looks like

```
int main()
{
    int result;
    (
        result = testFunction(1, 2);
        if(result != CR_SUCCESS)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    )
}
```

This is invalid, since you cannot have parentheses around statements.

For some things you might do when you want a macro which acts like a statement, see the C++ FAQ ["What should be done with macros that have multiple lines?"](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/misc-technical-issues#macros-with-multi-stmts)

Answer (score 0):

You should, as a general rule, avoid function-like macros as much as possible, there's very little need to use them in modern C++<sup>(a)</sup>. Most can be easily replaced with inline functions, or even non-inline functions if you trust the compiler to do the right thing.

I realise that's not appropriate for your *specific* use case since you need to exit the current function as part of the macro but I would ask you to think about *why* you think you need a macro for this case in the first place.

If it's to simply cut down on code lines, you can equally do that *without* a macro, such as with:

```cpp
if ((result = testFunction(1, 2)) != CR_SUCCESS) return -1;
```

That's equally as succinct (in terms of line count) and doesn't require you to go looking for the macro definition to see what's *actually* happening.

It also doesn't need all the normal faffing about trying to make sure your macros work in *all* places where they may be used, such as needing to use the `do { ... } while (0)` trick to ensure it works inside `if` or `else` blocks without braces. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-use-apparently-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-macros) and its answers for more explanation on that point.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> In fact, even *non-function-like* macros may be better replaced with enumerations (at least those such as a set of mutually exclusive value like error codes). Nowadays, I tend to use `#define` only for conditional compilation, on those relatively rare occasions where I need it.